# Display items grouped by a field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this example items collection:

```js
{
  "_id": "1",
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "category": "phones",
  "user": "1",
  "tags": [
    "tag1",
    "tag3"
  ]
},
{
  "_id": "2",
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "category": "phones",
  "user": "1",
  "tags": [
    "tag2",
    "tag3"
  ]
},
{
  "_id": "3",
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "category": "bikes",
  "user": "1",
  "tags": [
    "tag3",
    "tag4"
  ]
},
{
  "_id": "4",
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "category": "cars",
  "user": "2",
  "tags": [
    "tag1",
    "tag2"
  ]
}
```

I would to search items created by specific user (ie user: 1) and display them by category field. Result:

```js
{
  "phones": [
      {
        "_id": "1",
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
        "tags": [
          "tag1",
          "tag3"
         ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "2",
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
        "tags": [
          "tag2",
          "tag3"
         ]
      }
  ],
  "bikes" : [
      {
        "_id": "3",
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
        "tags": [
          "tag3",
          "tag4"
         ]
      }
  ]

}
```

Is it possible to obtain this scheme with aggregation-group functions?
Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to group by the category, but not in the way you present it. This is really a good thing because your "category" is actually data and you should really not be representing "data" as a "key", in either your storage or your output.

So it would really be recommended to transform like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "user": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$category",
        "items": { 
            "$push": {
                "field1": "$field1",
                "field2": "$field2",
                "tags": "$tags"
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "categories": { 
            "$push": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "items": "$items"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

You get output like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : null,
    "categories" : [
        {
            "_id" : "bikes",
            "items" : [
                {
                    "_id": 3,
                    "field1" : "value1",
                    "field2" : "value2",
                    "tags" : [
                        "tag3",
                        "tag4"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "phones",
            "items" : [
                {
                    "_id": 1,
                    "field1" : "value1",
                    "field2" : "value2",
                    "tags" : [
                        "tag1",
                        "tag3"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": 2,
                    "field1" : "value1",
                    "field2" : "value2",
                    "tags" : [
                        "tag2",
                        "tag3"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It really is better to have generic keys names that do not alter with the changing data. This is in fact the object oriented pattern.

If you really think you need the "data as keys" here, for the aggregation framework you either live with knowing the "categories" that you are expecting, or are otherwise prepared to generate the pipeline stages:

```js
db.utest.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "user": "1" } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "phones": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": ["$category","phones"] },
                    {
                        "_id": "$_id",
                        "field1": "$field1",
                        "field2": "$field2",
                        "tags": "$tags"
                    },
                    false
                ]
            }
        },
        "bikes": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": ["$category","bikes"] },
                    {
                        "_id": "$_id",
                        "field1": "$field1",
                        "field2": "$field2",
                        "tags": "$tags"
                    },
                    false
                ]
            }
        }           
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$phones" },
    { "$match": { "phones": { "$ne": false } }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "phones": { "$push": "$phones" },
        "bikes": { "$first": "$bikes" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$bikes" },
    { "$match": { "bikes": { "$ne": false } }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "phones": { "$first": "$phones" },
        "bikes": { "$push": "$bikes" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "phones": 1,
        "bikes": 1
    }}
])
```

You can shorten that a bit with MongoDB 2.6, since you can just filter out the `false` values with the [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operator:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "user": "1" } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "phones": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": ["$category","phones"] },
                    {
                        "_id": "$_id",
                        "field1": "$field1",
                        "field2": "$field2",
                        "tags": "$tags"
                    },
                    false
                ]
            }
        },
        "bikes": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": ["$category","bikes"] },
                    {
                        "_id": "$_id",
                        "field1": "$field1",
                        "field2": "$field2",
                        "tags": "$tags"
                    },
                    false
                ]
            }
        }           
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "phones": { "$setDifference": ["$phones",[false]] },
        "bikes": { "$setDifference": ["$bikes",[false]] }
    }}
])
```

Both produce output just how you want it:

```js
{
    "phones" : [
        {
            "_id" : "1",
            "field1" : "value1",
            "field2" : "value2",
            "tags" : [
                "tag1",
                "tag3"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "2",
            "field1" : "value1",
            "field2" : "value2",
            "tags" : [
                "tag2",
                "tag3"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "bikes" : [
        {
            "_id" : "3",
            "field1" : "value1",
            "field2" : "value2",
            "tags" : [
                "tag3",
                "tag4"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The general case here is that aggregation framework just **won't** allow field data to be used as a key, so you need to either just group on data or specify the key names yourself.

The only way you get "dynamic" key names is by using [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) instead:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function () {
      var obj = { };
      var category = this.category;
      delete this.user;
      delete this.category;

      obj[category] = [this];

      emit(null,obj);
    },
    function (key,values) {

      var reduced = {};

      values.forEach(function(value) {
        Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key) {
          if ( !reduced.hasOwnProperty(key) )
            reduced[key] = [];
          value[key].forEach(function(item) {
            reduced[key].push(item);
          });
        });
      });

      return reduced;

    },
    {
        "query": { "user": "1" },
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

So now the key generation is dynamic, but the output is done in a very mapReduce way:

```js
{
    "_id" : null,
    "value" : {
        "phones" : [
            {
                "_id" : "1",
                "field1" : "value1",
                "field2" : "value2",
                "tags" : [
                    "tag1",
                    "tag3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id" : "2",
                "field1" : "value1",
                "field2" : "value2",
                "tags" : [
                    "tag2",
                    "tag3"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "bikes" : [
            {
                "_id" : "3",
                "field1" : "value1",
                "field2" : "value2",
                "tags" : [
                    "tag3",
                    "tag4"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So the output is constrained by how mapReduce directs outut and evaluating the JavaScript here will be slower than the native operations of the aggregation framework. More power in manipulation, but that is the trade-off.

To conclude this, if you stick with the pattern then the first way with the aggregation framework is the fastest and best way to do this, plus you could always restructure the result once returned from the server. If you insist on breaking the pattern and need dynamic keys to come from the server then mapReduce will do it where the other aggregation framework is deemed impractical.

Comment: I really thanks You for The esplications. I think the first is the best solution becouse It respects the pattern, use The native aggregate function And finally The code is more simple for a newbie like me. Can You suggest me a simpler guide To learn The use or aggregate functions?

Comment: @Hadokee It probably is something I could look into considering a recent approach to write some technical articles. You can always look through questions here tagged for [aggregation-framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aggregation-framework) for examples, or generally in the documentation with guides like [SQL to Aggregation mapping](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) which covers some common cases if you are generally familiar with SQL.